# use of t-test to compare performance of algorithms

Tags: matlab, compare, computer-vision, stat

I need a little bit guidance. I have to compare the classification performance of multiple algorithms using simple or paired t-test.

Let's say I have three datasets (A,B,C) with training and test samples. I am running 3 algorithms (SIFT, SURF, ORB) and compute the classification accuracy such 0.9 means 90% of images correctly match from the test dataset.

Let' say I get the following table:

```
Dataset     SIFT      SURF      ORB
A          0.9        0.88     0.34
B          0.84       0.67     0.45
C          0.90       0.45     0.456
```

Can you please guide me how I can compare the performance of these algorithms using simple t-test? Tables clearly show that SIFT does better how can I use t-test to compute that thing?

Any guidance will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can't use a t-test with three points per group (computing the mean and standard deviation is not accurate)

Comment: infact i have 5-10 dataset measurements. This is just an example for analysis . . . bcz i have to use something anyway as i have been instructed to do so . . or any other simple test to measure ?

Comment: I'd take the question to [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), but you should also look into an ANOVA (`anova1`, `anova2`, `anovan`).

Answer (score 0):

classification accuracy difference between different algorithms can be evaluated by statistical methods, e.g. pairwise student T-test